# Anzure Search ingestion events

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-search

I'd like to know if Azure Search offers any ability to trigger an Azure Function when a document gets indexed or inserted into Azure search or if there are any other events I can take advantage of.

I'd like to avoid a timed event which continuously scans Azure search for new documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using an indexer, you can add a skillset with a [WebApiSkill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-custom-skill-web-api) to invoke your Azure Function for each inserted document. However, there's no transactional consistency guarantees - a document for which your function will be invoked is not guaranteed to be successfully inserted into the index.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a great way to do this today. Eugene's suggestion will work, but isn't super efficient and also does indeed have the limitation of the document might not actually make it to the index if something else goes wrong later in the indexer. Please vote on the following uservoice item which is related to implementation for triggered events for Azure Cognitive Search if you are interested in seeing a more well defined option for this scenario: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/10095111-azure-search-alerts